# Premake exclude project

Tags: c++, premake

I have a main premake lua file in root with the workspace declaration and some basic configurations and at the end of that file I include the projects.

```
workspace "Test"
    CONFIGURATIONS

    include "Project1"
    include "Project2"
    include "Project3"
```

On linux I want to exclude "Project 3" as it's not needed to compile it there.
I tried defining systems and using filters but the file still gets generated.

To generate the makefiles on linux I use **premake gmake2**.

Answer (score 0):

On recent versions of Premake5:

```lua
if _TARGET_OS ~= "linux" then
   include "Project3"
end
```

On older versions:

```lua
if _OS ~= "linux" then
   include "Project3"
end
```