# Exclude project from build by Premake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, premake

I have two projects in the solution. One of them is a debug lib, which should be built only in Debug workspace configuration. In VS I can just disable the 'Build' checkbox in Configuration Manager.

[image]

But I need this to be done with Premake 5.0, which include all project in build by default.
I tried to use filter by configuration, but this didn't worked for me.

```
solution "Workspace"

configurations 
{   
    "Debug",
    "Release"
}

project "Application"
    language "C++"
    kind "ConsoleApp"

    files
    {
        "../sources/**.hpp",
        "../sources/**.cpp",
    }

filter "configurations:Debug"   

project "DebugLib"
    language "C++"
    kind "StaticLib"

    files
    {
        "../sources/**.hpp",
        "../sources/**.cpp",
    }
    
filter {}
```

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686766/premake-exclude-project) way could for me, but I didn't find how to make if condition with solution configuration.

How can I achieve this behaviour with Premake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dived into project [kind](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/kind) and find out that `None` kind can suit my needs.

> A configuration which is not included in the build. Useful for
> projects containing only web pages, header files, or support
> documentation.

I changed my config, and put kind under the filter by configuration, which solved the problem. Now
it looks this way:

```
project "DebugLib"
    language "C++"
    
    filter "configurations:Release" 
        kind "None"
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        kind "StaticLib"
    filter {}
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here but should you not be able to just
to this workspace use configmap to manage this?

https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Configurations-and-Platforms

use the filter.

```
project "Application"
   configurations { "Release" }
   kind "ConsoleApp"
   targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
    filter "configurations:Release"
```

as shown here https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/kind

and I pretty sure you can use https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Build-Settings
to get the appropriate settings to have control of the platform needed.

you can also probably just use defines keyword as well that basically goes.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already marked an accepted solution but I thought I would leave this here in the hope of helping future searchers.

I needed my project to be a utility project so that I could still manually compile items from within the project, which I could not do if the project kind is changed to 'None'.

So I ended up adding this.

```
require('vstudio')

premake.api.register {
    name = "buildenabled",
    scope = "config",
    kind = "string",
    allowed = {
        "Default",
        "Off",
        "On"
    },
  }
  
-- \modules\vstudio\vs2005_solution.lua
premake.override(premake.vstudio.sln2005.elements, "projectConfigurationPlatforms", function(base, cfg, context)
    
    if context.prjCfg.buildenabled and context.prjCfg.buildenabled == "Off" then
        return {
            premake.vstudio.sln2005.activeCfg
        }
    else
        return base(cfg, context)
    end
  end)
```

Then inside a project you want to disable the build you just add

```
buildenabled "Off"
```

to disable the project.

It's very rough but might help others find a solution that works for them.